# In TFS, can I use an added 'In Progress' state to determine how long tasks take?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I've modified the Agile task template in TFS to include a new 'In Progress' state.  When work is started on an item the 'assigned user' will set the task from 'Active' to 'In Progress'.  This helps me to know which tasks have been started.

I was, however, thinking that I might be able to use this new state to figure out how long things take.  Is there a way I could get the difference between the 'State Change Date' for 'In Progess' and 'Closed' states?

The out-of-the-box TFS queries seem to be limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to TFS so I am not sure if this is already built can't confirm, but one option you have is to add two new fields to the workitem, for the start and stop dates. You can have the worflow set those variables when you transition into and outof a state.

Comment: Thanks, you've clued me in on using the existing fields 'Start Date' and 'Finish Date' to accomplish this.  These fields are currently disabled by default, so I can set them during the state transitions from 'Active' to 'In Progress' and 'In Progress' to 'Closed'.

Comment: Awsome glad I was able to help! I can't wait to regen this old server I just got back to upgrade to TFS;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to the answer as well.

One thing to take into account, though, is that if a task runs over a weekend, you would not want those days to be taken into account if you are looking for a measure of "developer days".  Taking it a step further, it would be nice to be able to somehow define days that work would not happen on (such as when the office is closed) to get a more accurate reflection of the time spent.

Comment: Yes, you're right that it's going to be a very gross estimate.  I'm trying not to over burden the developers with updating the 'Remaining Work' field.  Although, I may consider this in the future.

Comment: Exactly.  I don't want to go to the extreme where it gets in the way of the developers.  There are some tools available to speed up the time entry aspect on CodePlex, but I was hoping to work within the data available.